# How to forcefully close a ssh connection is the command on the target server never returns

Tags: ssh, timeout, hang, pkill

I have an automation tool that generates and executes the below command that fires `rpm -qa  grep httpd` on the target host 10.9.100.67.

```
ssh -vvv -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="/app/ssh_keys/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="root"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=8 10.9.100.67 'rpm -qa | grep httpd'
```

Note: the ssh connection command above works fine and I'm able to successfully connect from 10.9.50.20 (source) to target host 10.9.100.67

The problem is with the server 10.9.100.67. If we login to 10.9.100.67 server and fire the  `rpm -qa | grep httpd` it hangs and not even `Ctrl+C` on my putty shell helps. There is no option but to kill the putty session.

The requirement for this post is not to address the `rpm -qa | grep httpd` hanging on 10.9.100.67 issue; but what I need is my `ssh` on 10.9.50.20 to close the connection with target 10.9.100.67 if the command does not respond with a failure or success in 5 minutes duration.

I even tried the command timeout option but the ssh control does not comeback to source.

```
ssh -vvv -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="/app/ssh_keys/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="root"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=8 10.9.100.67 'timeout 5s rpm -qa | grep httpd'
```

Note: `-o ConnectTimeout=10` does not help and the ssh simply never returns back to 10.9.50.20 from 10.9.100.67 which is what want.

Below command from stackoverflow help but does not work for AiX systems as pkill is not present.

```
ssh 10.9.100.67 '( sleep 60 && kill -9 0 ) 2>/dev/null & rpm -qa | grep httpd; RC=$? ; sleep 1 ; pkill -P $! ; exit $RC'
```

Can you help with the solution that works on AIX as well ?

Comment: Mind you, you have an XY-problem, where X is the problem with `rpm`. It might be (for example) a corrupted database or some shared-library inconsistency.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative solution if you just want to run `rpm -qa | grep httpd` on the remote host, there is a tool `sshpass`. You can refer to this link for installation and common usage.

https://www.tecmint.com/sshpass-non-interactive-ssh-login-shell-script-ssh-password/

Comment: How does this address my hung issue @Gautham Sreenivaz? Can you please explain further ?

Comment: `sshpass` is a tool for password interactive ssh session on a remote server. It also has a feature to execute a command remotely and return back to the shell, the output can be ignored, append to a file based on your requirement. if there is any halt in the session, the command returns to the shell after a particular time period.